# How to create a cumulative report based on differences between data updated daily in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am trying to create a report from another report(source sheet). :)
The source sheet updates daily automatically by inserting new rows with progress on sales on top of the rows completed a day before:

| Date | Product | Units sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/15 | A | 35 |
| 11/15 | B | 12 |
| 11/15 | C | 18 |
| 11/14 | A | 30 |
| 11/14 | C | 11 |
| 11/14 | B | 10 |
| 11/13 | F | 88 |
| 11/12 | B | 7 |
| 11/12 | A | 29 |
| 11/12 | C | 10 |
| 11/11 | C | 8 |
| 11/11 | A | 29 |
| 11/11 | B | 3 |

The "Units sold" column is cumulative meaning that a newer record on a certain product will show a greater or equal value to a previous record on that specific product.
New products appear in the source sheet when entering the company and they disappear from it when they are sold out, pretty much randomly. (e.g. product "F" that showed up and sold out in the same day)
In the first column in the source report i already found a formula that concatenates date and product and is used by another reports.

To solve this, in the results report i made on column T the same concat of date and product. Then, in my new report, in the results column, i used the following formula: =vlookup(T2,Source!$A2:$C$10000,3,0)-vlookup(T2,Source!$A3:$C$10000,3,0) with the intention to obtain the difference between the amount of products sold in the last day vs the amount of products sold in the day before it, or, better said, the amount of each of the products sold on a specific date. Finally, by using a column of =year() and one of =month() applied on date column and a couple of pivot tables i was able to obtain the value of the daily increment for each and/or year.

The problem i couldn't find a solution for is that when the source sheet updates, the new rows added with the freshest data move down the cell references from the vlookup formula i used in the results sheet.
Please help me find a way to "pin down" the cell references in the vlookup formula without being affected by the new rows insertions.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share an example sheet of it? What is the end goal here and what do you mean by `find a way to "pin down" the cell references in the vlookup formula without bein affected by the new rows insertions`

Comment: @Kessy, the end goal is to create a set of absolute cell refferences for my vlookup formula, that will not move down as new rows are inserted at the top of my source data sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to "pin down" the references you can use `INDIRECT`

example:

```
A1:A >>> INDIRECT("A1:A")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Does indirect work with references to different sheet?

Comment: @vtor sure: `INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:A")`

Comment: Great! Thank you!